# Properly aligning drawn lines between the corners of 2 rectangular nodes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I draw a thick line from the corner of one box to the same corner of another, it doesn't attach properly. See the code and picture below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, thick, minimum size=1cm] (a) {A};
  \node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, right=2cm of a] (b) {B};

  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.north west) -- (b.north west);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.north east) -- (b.north east);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.south west) -- (b.south west);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.south east) -- (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I make the lines attach exactly to the corners and not slightly off as in this example?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Very good question!

First, the explanation.  When TikZ/PGF creates a node, then it stores various associated locations as "anchors".  These can be used to refer to points on the node other than its main coordinate (its centre).  A very common family of anchors is the border of the node, these can be referred to by angle, as in `(node.45)` or by compass direction, as in `(node.north west)`.  Although the node can define rules as it likes for these, the basic nodes tend to position these so that they are the sensible choice of point on the boundary of the node (an example of "sensible": on a rectangular node `(node.north west)` is always a corner).

The key phrase here is "**on the boundary of the node**".  The line width is crucial here.  If you write:

```
\node[red,draw, minimum size=2cm] (a) {};
\draw[<-] (a) -- ++(5,0);
```

then you want the arrow to stop at the *edge* of the boundary, not the middle of the boundary.  If we make the line width ridiculous, then we can see the effect:

[image: node boundary with line width]

The arrow stops at the edge of the node boundary, not at the mid-point.  To get the mid-point, we have to lengthen the line by half the line width.  However, that's not a good solution since we need to use the line width that was in effect at the time that the node was drawn (which might not be the current line width) and it only works if the line is orthogonal to the boundary, otherwise we need to adjust the offset.

Better would be if the node itself knew of this "mid-boundary".  There are two ways to do this that I can think of straight away.  One is to define a new node shape where the anchor boundary was not adjusted by the line width.  This would be fairly easy to do: copy the definition from the right file and make the necessary adjustments, but isn't something that I'd recommend for a one-shot picture or to someone not happy with `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`.  If this is something that you're likely to use a lot then say so, and I'll help make the modifications if you need help.

A quicker (and dirtier) way of doing this is to separate the drawing of the border from its use as a way of setting the anchors.  Two ways to do this spring to mind: use two nodes, or use one with a post- or pre-action.  In the first case, you define a node which is not drawn but which defines the shape.  Then you put on top a new node which is drawn.  Then you refer to the *first* for the anchors.  The second case is in effect the same, except that you combine the commands into one which avoids creating extra objects and unnecessary duplication of commands.

Here's the above example done the first way:

```
\node[minimum size=2cm,postaction={draw,thick,red},line width=0cm] (a) {};
\draw[<-] (a) -- ++(5,0);
```

We do have to specify the line width on the action, even if it is a pre-action, since the `line width=0cm` gets set immediately.  It would be possible to define a way of saving the current line width and restoring it within the action.

Here's the same example with two nodes:

```
\node[minimum size=2cm,line width=0cm] (a) {};
\node[draw,red,minimum size=2cm] at (a) {};
\draw[<-] (a) -- ++(5,0);
```

The important thing with this one is to ensure that any size commands on the first are replicated.  What would get difficult with this would be if the size of the node was determined by its contents.

Both of these produce the following:

[image: node with arrow in boundary]

Now we can see that the arrow goes where it should.

If we add this to your code, we can see its effect.  To emphasis the effect, I've increased the line width to 1mm and drawn the dashed lines as solid red.

[image: lines ending in corners]

(Notice another effect of this shifting of anchors.  Since the righthand square is positioned relative to the first, changing the node boundary changes its position ever-so slightly.)

To make it easier to code, I did what I suggested above and defined some keys.  Thus the node itself is defined as:

```
\node [draw with anchor in boundary, minimum size=1cm] (a) {A};
```

The full code (for the above with both versions) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29874/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newdimen\zerolinewidth

\tikzset{
  zero line width/.code={%
    \zerolinewidth=\pgflinewidth
    \tikzset{line width=0cm}%
  },
  use line width/.code={%
    \tikzset{line width=\the\zerolinewidth}%
  },
  draw with anchor in boundary/.style={
    zero line width,
    postaction={draw,use line width},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
  \node [draw, minimum size=1cm] (a) {A};
  \node [draw, minimum size=3cm, right=2cm of a] (b) {B};

  \draw [red] (a.north west) -- (b.north west);
  \draw [red] (a.north east) -- (b.north east);
  \draw [red] (a.south west) -- (b.south west);
  \draw [red] (a.south east) -- (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
  \node [draw with anchor in boundary, minimum size=1cm] (a) {A};
  \node [draw with anchor in boundary, minimum size=3cm, right=2cm of a] (b) {B};

  \draw [red] (a.north west) -- (b.north west);
  \draw [red] (a.north east) -- (b.north east);
  \draw [red] (a.south west) -- (b.south west);
  \draw [red] (a.south east) -- (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** The choice of `preaction` or `postaction` was initially arbitrary, but having seen the updated question I realise that I chose the wrong one.  It should (as it now is) be a **postaction**.  This is so that if the node is filled (which can be done on the main node as it isn't affected by line width) and then drawn then the draw should be done *second* so that it is on top of the fill.  Otherwise the fill takes out half of the line width (as seen in the updated question).

Comment: Excellent answer! However, I have one problem: the lines of the _boxes_ are no longer `semithick` (my default setting) but TikZ default thickness which is `thin`. Since we're explicitly dealing with `line width` here, how do I set it to be semithick?

Comment: @gablin: The easy solution is to specify the `semithick` option **before** the `draw with anchor in boundary` option.  That seems to work.  The `draw with anchor in boundary` saves the line width that is in effect at the time that it is used.  Ensuring that it worked with setting the line width afterwards would be possible, but would involve Deep Hackery.

Comment: Hm, the problem seems to be with the `fill` option. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @gablin: Mea culpa.  With shapes (and nodes), `fill`s should always be done before `draws`.  Since I was using a `preaction`, the draw was happening before the fill.  I've changed it to a `postaction` which corrects this.  Hopefully that now fixes it (let me know!).

Answer (score 11):

Why not use `outer sep=0pt` for the first nodes, By default `outer sep=0.5\pgflinewidth` I think it's enough to get a good result. The two last pictures are the same with `draw with anchor in boundary`or `outer sep=0pt`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29874/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newdimen\zerolinewidth

\tikzset{
  zero line width/.code={%
    \zerolinewidth=\pgflinewidth
    \tikzset{line width=0cm}%
  },
  use line width/.code={%
    \tikzset{line width=\the\zerolinewidth}%
  },
  draw with anchor in boundary/.style={
    zero line width,
    postaction={draw,use line width},
  },
}

\begin{document} 

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, thick, minimum size=1cm,outer sep=0pt] (a) {A};
  \node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, right=2cm of a,outer sep=0pt] (b) {B};

  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.north west) -- (b.north west);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.north east) -- (b.north east);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.south west) -- (b.south west);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.south east) -- (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
  \node [draw, minimum size=1cm,outer sep=0pt] (a) {A};
  \node [draw, minimum size=3cm, right=2cm of a,outer sep=0pt] (b) {B};

  \draw [red] (a.north west) -- (b.north west);
  \draw [red] (a.north east) -- (b.north east);
  \draw [red] (a.south west) -- (b.south west);
  \draw [red] (a.south east) -- (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
  \node [draw with anchor in boundary, minimum size=1cm] (a) {A};
  \node [draw with anchor in boundary, minimum size=3cm, right=2cm of a] (b) {B};

  \draw [red] (a.north west) -- (b.north west);
  \draw [red] (a.north east) -- (b.north east);
  \draw [red] (a.south west) -- (b.south west);
  \draw [red] (a.south east) -- (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking for a solution to stack nodes exactly on top of each other with the boundaries exactly overlapping. This did the trick and is as simple, as I expected it from tikz! 
This is what I wanted: `\draw[ultra thick,outer sep=0] node[draw](bot){bottom} (bot.north) node[draw=red,above]{top};`

Answer (score 7):

[Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29880/16595) gives an excellent explanation why the lines only touch the node’s border and [Alain Matthes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47002/16595) gives a solution that is in this simple case superior (and essentially the same).

I want to give another solution that does not rely on the `outer sep`s settings or in fact on the original anchors (the original anchors on the boundary are lost and even a simple `\draw (a) -- (b);` line will extend into the rectangle’s border).

Inspired by [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14772/16595)’s answer to a question [that asks for more anchors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14769/16595) I actually added more anchors to the `rectangular` shape.

All anchors that lie on the border (all compass points as well as `.mid west`, `.base west`, `.mid east` and `.base east`) are duplicated to `line <old anchor name>`, e.g. `.line north west`, `.line north`, `.line mid east` and so forth.

Just like all original anchors are based on two “saved” anchors (namely `north east` and `south west`) the “line” anchors are based on `line north east` and `line south west` whose calculation is as simple as it gets: Their definition is nearly the same as from `north east` and `south west`; only the values of `outer xsep` and `outer ysep` are not used.

In this answer three outputs are given:

- with the settings given from the question’s code
- with extra “debug” settings (thicker and solid lines, opacity)
- and a reduced clone of the Rectangle figure of the PGF manual (section 48.2 “Predefined Shapes”, page 420) that shows the new anchors and their old companions.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
% The macro \pgfaddtoshape is originally from Martin Scharrer
& https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14772/16595
% and here extended to be able to use \savedanchor and \nodeparts/\pgfnodepartstextbox
\def\pgfaddtoshape#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\pgf@sm@shape@name{#1}%
  \let\savedanchor=\pgf@sh@savedanchor
  \let\anchor=\pgf@sh@anchor
  \let\nodeparts=\pgf@sh@boxes
  \nodeparts{text}%
  #2%
  \endgroup
}
%

\pgfaddtoshape{rectangle}{
    \savedanchor\linesouthwest{%
        \pgf@x=\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
        \advance\pgf@x by 2\pgf@xc%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@xb%
            \pgf@x=\pgf@xb%
        \fi%
        \pgf@x=-.5\pgf@x%
        \advance\pgf@x by.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y=\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
        \advance\pgf@y by 2\pgf@yc%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@y<\pgf@yb
            \pgf@y=\pgf@yb
        \fi%
        \pgf@y=-.5\pgf@y%
        \advance\pgf@y by-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }
    \anchor{line south west}{\linesouthwest}
    \savedanchor\linenortheast{%
        \pgf@x=\the\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
        \advance\pgf@x by 2\pgf@xc%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgf@xb%
          \pgf@x=\pgf@xb%
        \fi%
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x%
        \advance\pgf@x by.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgf@y=\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
        \advance\pgf@y by 2\pgf@yc%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
        \ifdim\pgf@y<\pgf@yb%
          \pgf@y=\pgf@yb%
        \fi%
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
        \advance\pgf@y by-.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
        \advance\pgf@y by.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    }
    \anchor{line north east}{\linenortheast}
    \anchor{line north west}{
        \pgf@process{\linesouthwest}
        \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
        \pgf@process{\linenortheast}
        \pgf@x=\pgf@xa
    }
    \anchor{line south east}{
        \pgf@process{\linesouthwest}
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \pgf@process{\linenortheast}
        \pgf@y=\pgf@ya
    }
    \anchor{line north}{
        \pgf@process{\linesouthwest}%
        \pgf@xa=.5\pgf@x%
        \pgf@process{\linenortheast}%
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x%
        \advance\pgf@x by \pgf@xa%
    }
    \anchor{line south}{
        \pgf@process{\linenortheast}%
        \pgf@xa=.5\pgf@x%
        \pgf@process{\linesouthwest}%
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x%
        \advance\pgf@x by \pgf@xa%
    }
    \anchor{line west}{
        \pgf@process{\linenortheast}%
        \pgf@ya=.5\pgf@y%
        \pgf@process{\linesouthwest}%
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
        \advance\pgf@y by \pgf@ya%
    }
    \anchor{line mid west}{\linesouthwest\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{.5ex}}
    \anchor{line base west}{\linesouthwest\pgf@y=0pt}
    \anchor{line east}{%
        \pgf@process{\linesouthwest}%
        \pgf@ya=.5\pgf@y%
        \pgf@process{\linenortheast}%
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y%
        \advance\pgf@y by \pgf@ya%
    }
    \anchor{line mid east}{\linenortheast\pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{.5ex}}
    \anchor{line base east}{\linenortheast\pgf@y=0pt}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%   thick/.style={line width=10pt},% debug
%   dashed/.style={solid},% debug
%   opacity=.5
]
  \node [draw, thick, minimum size=1cm] (a) {A};
  \node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, right=2cm of a] (b) {B};

  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.line north west) -- (b.line north west);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.line north east) -- (b.line north east);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.line south west) -- (b.line south west);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (a.line south east) -- (b.line south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Output (with debug settings)

[image]

### Rectangle’s anchors

[image]