# Understanding TikZ node placement

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having a hard time understanding how TikZ uses space

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{red/.style={fill=red,circle,inner sep=0pt}}
\tikzset{green/.style={fill=green,circle,inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
  \draw[help lines,step=.2] (-2,-1) grid (-1,0);
 \draw[help lines,line width=.5pt,step=1] (-2,-1) grid (2,1);
 \foreach \x in {-2,-1}
 \node[anchor=north] at (\x,-1) {\x};
 \foreach \y in {-1,0}
 \node[anchor=east] at (-2,\y) {\y};
 \node [rectangle,inner xsep=20mm,inner ysep=10mm,line width=.5pt](fr){};

 \node [red,anchor=center] at (fr.south west){};
 \node [green,anchor=center] at (-2,-1)(sw){};
 \node [green,right=2mm of sw.center](r){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1) If you compile the above code you'll see that the red dot, which is placed with a relative coordinate, and the green one which is placed with numerical coordinates do not overlap perfectly. Why is that?

2) the node labeled r is not placed where it should be but a bit on the right, even if the distance is specified from sw.center. Why?

Comment: I believe that the entire reason for this is the `inner sep` of a node.  If you change `xsep=20mm,inner ysep=10mm` to `inner xsep=0mm,inner ysep=0mm` the two are aligned exactly on top of each other. So `fr.south west` is not `(-2.-1)`. The two are offset by the diagonal of the two `inner sep`s you added. Anohter possible confusion is that the `anchor=center` refers to the `center` of the new node you are placing, _not_ the coordinate defined by the `at` option.

Comment: @PeterGrill it doesn't do what you describe here. Also if you set x=0 y=0 the reference rectangle collapses to its center

Comment: The anchors are placed at the border of the line (which has a width), this is done by a default `outer sep` (`outer xsep`/`outer ysep`) of `.5\pgflinewidth`. Setting these to `+0pt` places the anchors in the middle of the line. See also [\[1\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29874). The `right` key automatically also sets `anchor=west` (which is usually what you want), so you need to do `right=2mm of sw.center,anchor=center`. The `on grid` option makes this the default behavior. See also [\[2\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94386) and [\[3\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the placing of the red node, the line width is being taken into account.  For the second green dot, the node border is being used as reference, you should use `on grid` to ignore that.

[image: Sample zoomed output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{red/.style={fill=red,circle,inner sep=0pt}}
\tikzset{green/.style={fill=green,circle,inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
  \draw[help lines,step=.2] (-2,-1) grid (-1,0);
  \draw[help lines,line width=.5pt,step=1] (-2,-1) grid (2,1);
  \foreach \x in {-2,-1}
    \node[anchor=north] at (\x,-1) {\x};
  \foreach \y in {-1,0}
    \node[anchor=east] at (-2,\y) {\y};
  \node [rectangle,inner xsep=20mm,inner ysep=10mm,line width=.5pt](fr){};

  \node [red,anchor=center] at ($(fr.south west)+(.25pt,.25pt)$) {};
  \node [green,anchor=center] at (-2,-1) (sw) {};
  \node [green,anchor=center,on grid,right=2mm of sw](r){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: so when you place node relatively to another also the border of the target node is taken in consideration? On grid is like saying: "right= 22 of sw.center, put the center of the new node here", right?

Comment: Yes, without `on grid` the border of the target is used.