# Arrow badly connected with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows

I'm making a small scheme with TIKZ (and KTIKZ) and I have a problem when drawing an arrow between two node.
I want to draw an arrow from `B` to `C` by using the `\draw` with the following script :

```
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [circle, rounded corners,text centered,text width=2cm,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=20mm, draw=black, fill=blue!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (A) [startstop] {A};
\node at (A.east) (B) [startstop] {B};
\node at (B.south) (C) [startstop] {C};
\draw [line width=1mm,->,>=stealth]  (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I have the following result :

[image]

**Do you know what is wrong ?**

Comment: outer sep is too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that are making code give unintuitive result. If we fix the node locations and change the path a bit, it is easier to see,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[startstop/.style={circle,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=18mm,draw=black,fill=blue!50}]
\node[startstop] (A)  {A};
\node[startstop] (B)  at (2,0) {B};
\node[startstop] (C)  at (2,-2) {C};
\draw[line width=1mm,->,>=stealth]  (B) -- (C);
\draw[red,opacity=0.25] (B) circle (1.8cm+1ex) (C) circle (1.8cm+1ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

you can see that the point of the border of `B` is now almost on `C` but the point it needs to draw it is almost on `B`. That's the effect of `outer sep` that adds a separation around the node shape. If you increase back to 2cm outer sep the arrow flips.

I think you have chosen to do this because you wanted to have a relative placement of the nodes. What you should have been doing is the `positioning` syntax.

```
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}% In the preamble 


    \begin{tikzpicture}[startstop/.style={circle,
                                          inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0,
                                          draw=black,fill=blue!50,
                                          minimum width=2cm}
                       ]
    \node[startstop] (A)  {A};
    \node[startstop,right= 2cm of A] (B)  {B};
    \node[startstop,below= 2cm of B] (C) {C};
    \draw [line width=1mm,->,>=stealth]  (B) -- (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
Now you can see that no matter how big the nodes are they are still 2 cm apart. You can skip the `2cm` declaration and just say `right = of A` then the distance is read from the value of the `node distance`. So if you set it up in the picture options it is the same for all calls to that syntax.

Also notice that to be able to change node size, you don't need to play with the text width or height. The shape size can be changed via minimum height width keys.

More info about these are always in the manual but here are a few related posts appeared previously here.

- [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)
- [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)
- [In TikZ, what are the coordinates "node" uses to "draw"? (the effects of the difference between "inner sep" and "outer sep")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212361/in-tikz-what-are-the-coordinates-node-uses-to-draw-the-effects-of-the-dif)