# Cannot use \endextracode in tikz-timing

Tags: tables, tikz-timing

The manual claims that `\extracode` could be ended by `\endextracode` so one may add more rows after some TeX-thing happens.

But this code does not compile. Seems like the function of `&` was not switched back.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikztimingtable}
        A & 10M \\
    \extracode\endextracode
        B & 20M \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

The log file is even more interesting:

```
 Missing character: There is no B in font nullfont!
 
 ./Untitled-6.tex:7: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
 l.7        B &
           20M \\
 ?
```

Actually I did not find any single piece of working example. I guess this is the expected syntax?

By the way, I am using MacTeX and I *just* updated my packages.

Comment: This macro is only defined inside a `{tikztimingtable}` environment and can only be used after the last table line (i.e. after a \\).

Comment: @ferahfeza That is how all examples do the job. But the manual then claims **From version 0.7 on it is possible to add further timing rows after an extracode section by using \endextracode.** Without any concrete example I cannot figure what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be indeed a bug in `tikz-timing`. Please always open a bug report for these at the [package project site](https://sourceforge.net/p/tikz-timing/tickets/). I, as the package author, keep missing some of such posts otherwise.

You can fix this in the meantime by enabling the continuation of the `tikz-timing` row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{tikz-timing}{2020/10/01}{}{%
\def\tikztiming@endextracode{\tikztimingtable@row}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikztimingtable}
        A & 10M \\
\extracode
    \relax
\endextracode
        B & 20M \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```