# How to provide a package bugfix if the package maintainer does not respond?

Tags: updating, tikz-timing

After a question here, a bugfix was developed for the tikz-timing package (subpackage advnodes).

- I posted this question and also it's solution as an issue on the original code repo, but go no response.
- I additionally wrote a email but got no response.

How can I update the package?

Moreover, there is a new feature which was also developed at tex.se, that could be added to tikz-timing.

Comment: Is the maintainer a TeX.SX member? Perhaps you should add a link to the question you refer to

Comment: @ChristianHupfer not just a member, he's a mod:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ah, an idol;-) Well, a mod can be pinged somehow ;-)

Comment: You can't update the package other than mail Martin and ask that he update it however it is LPPL licenced so if you do not want to wait, or want to extend it in other ways nothing is preventing you distributing a modified package under a new name.

Comment: I assume you mean [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234933/1090) which was only posted a couple of weeks ago, that is a totally unreasonable timeframe to expect a response and talk of forcing package updates.

Comment: I don't expect an immediate update on CTAN, but there is a bug report system on bitbucket and I would acknoledge a short response to so every one can see there is work in progress/bug acepted message. The bug itself is known for months and the question on tex.se is not the first one concerning undefined control sequences in advnodes. There are actually even more bugs in it. My mail to Mr. Scharrer is more than 2 weeks old. I was just asking how to proceed in such a case and which opinions do exist. I don't want to force any thing or create a package clone :)

Comment: @Paebbels: I answer mails to my closest friends even in a four weeks schedule, depending on time. So please be patient if Martin Scharrer does not answer *immediately* ;-)

Comment: If you don't want to clone, then the way to proceed is to wait and be patient. Do remember that, in addition to a fortnight being a ridiculously short period, the most recent fortnight has included several public holidays in many countries and lots of people haven't even been reading their email - never mind replying to it.

Comment: Do also note, that the fix posted in that answer might not be usable in that form for reasons which are non-obvious. Or that answer might have failed to identify the real bug. Even if the answer works, it might have unintended side-effects (especially since the author admits to not using the library themselves). The fact that it solves the problem for you does not show that it is acceptable as a general bugfix. It could be a useful workaround for you but not solve anything for other users. (Indeed, given the author, it will probably cause more problems than it solves.)

Comment: I have comments on packages going back 20 years, after two weeks I wouldn't even have expected that the message has been read never mind acted on. You don't need to proceed, If you have reported a bug you have already done more than most.