# How to draw state transition diagrams like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm doing a project on epidemiologies and I am reading a paper of which I really like the appearance of the transition state diagrams, but I can not get mine to look as good. Having an example would be a life saver. This is how they look on the article [image: Example diagram]

and this is how mine look

[image: My diagram]

Here's my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{node distance=2.3cm, auto}
\node (0) {\footnotesize$\pi (S+V)$};
\node (1) [right of=0, xshift = -0.5cm, shape=rectangle,draw=black, fill=cyan] {$S$}; 
\node (2) [right of=1, shape=rectangle,draw=black, fill=white] {$E$};
\node (3) [right of=2, shape = rectangle, draw = black, fill = red] {$Z$};
\node (4) [below of=2, yshift=1cm] {\footnotesize$\alpha E$};
\node (5) [below of=3, yshift=1cm] {\footnotesize$\gamma (S+ V)Z$};
\node (6) [right of = 3, draw = black, fill = green] {$V$};
\node (7) [below of=6, shape = rectangle, yshift=1cm, text = white] {$V$};
\path (1.east) -- (1.north east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a1);
\path (2.west) -- (2.north west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b1);  
\path (6.south) -- (6.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a6);
\path (6.south) -- (6.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b6);
\path (7.north) -- (7.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a7);
\path (7.south) -- (7.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b7);
\draw[->] (0) to node {} (1);
\draw[->] (a1) to node {\footnotesize$\beta SZ$} (b1);
\path (1.east) -- (1.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a2);
\path (2.west) -- (2.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b2);
\draw[->] (a2) to[swap] node {\footnotesize$\delta S$} (b2);
\draw[->] (3) to node{} (5);
\draw[->] (2) to node{} (4);
\draw[->] (2) to node{\footnotesize $(1-\alpha)\lambda E$} (3);
\draw[->] (1) to[in=135,out=45]  node{\footnotesize$\zeta S$} (6);
\draw[->] (a6) to node{\footnotesize$\delta V$} (a7);
\draw[->] (b6) to[swap] node{\footnotesize$\beta VZ$} (b7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a go at not only duplicating the style but also simplifying the code for increased ease of consistency/reusability.

I defined three `style`s: `transition`, `state`, and `statecolor`. `transition` is to be used for connecting arrows, and `state` for plain states such as `E` in this diagram. `statecolor` inherits all settings from the `state` style, but adds `fill` and `draw` colors based on an argument passed into the style key like so: `statecolor=red`.

`>=stealth` sets `stealth` arrow tips globally. `node distance=2, on grid` sets the `positioning` library up for nodes `2cm` apart, center-to-center.

I converted each positioned `node` to use the preferred `=of` syntax for use with the `positioning` library. I also added the `calc` library to negate the need for the temporary coordinates on the node edges. If many states have multiple transitions, it may be convenient to add additional anchors to the shape, as described in [Add more anchors to standard Tikz nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14769/add-more-anchors-to-standard-tikz-nodes).

The complete revised code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
  transition/.style={font=\footnotesize, auto, inner sep=0.5ex},
  state/.style={font=\large, minimum size=1cm, draw, fill=white},
  statecolor/.style={state, draw=#1!70, fill=#1!30},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, node distance=2, on grid]
\node (S) [statecolor=blue] {$S$}; 
\node (E) [right=of S,state] {$E$};
\node (Z) [right=of E,statecolor=red] {$Z$};
\node (V) [right=of Z,statecolor=green] {$V$};
\draw[<-] (S) to +(-1,0) node[transition,left] {$\pi (S+V)$};
\draw[->] ($(S.east)!0.5!(S.north east)$) to node[transition] {$\beta SZ$} ($(E.west)!0.5!(E.north west)$);
\draw[->] ($(S.east)!0.5!(S.south east)$) to[swap,transition] node {$\delta S$} ($(E.west)!0.5!(E.south west)$);
\draw[->] (Z) to +(0,-1) node[transition,below] {$\gamma (S+ V)Z$};
\draw[->] (E) to +(0,-1) node[transition,below] {$(1-\alpha)\chi E$};
\draw[->] (E) to node[transition] { $\alpha\lambda E$} (Z);
\draw[->] (S) -- +(0,1) -| node[pos=0.25,transition] {$\zeta S$} (V);
\draw[->] ($(V.south)!0.5!(V.south east)$) to +(0,-1) node[transition,below] {$\beta VZ$};
\draw[->] ($(V.south)!0.5!(V.south west)$) to +(0,-0.5) node[transition,below] {$\delta V$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Add a style file for `my rect` that can change the size of the rectangle. Also, it seems that node (7) is not needed and marked out in this new update.

```
\tikzset{my rect/.style={draw,shape=rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm}}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,positioning,shapes,calc}
\tikzset{my rect/.style={draw,shape=rectangle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{node distance=2.3cm, auto}
\node (0) {\footnotesize$\pi (S+V)$};
\node (1) [right of=0, xshift = -0.5cm, my rect,draw=black, fill=cyan!30!white] {$S$}; 
\node (2) [right of=1, my rect, draw=gray, fill=white] {$E$};
\node (3) [right of=2, my rect, draw=red, fill = red!30!white] {$Z$};
\node (4) [below of=2, yshift=1cm] {\footnotesize$(1-\alpha)\chi E$};
\node (5) [below of=3, yshift=1cm] {\footnotesize$\gamma (S+ V)Z$};
\node (6) [right of = 3, draw=green, my rect, fill = green!30!white] {$V$};
%\node (7) [below of=6, yshift=1cm, text = white] {$V$};
\path (1.east) -- (1.north east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a1);
\path (2.west) -- (2.north west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b1);  
%\path (6.south) -- (6.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a6);
%\path (6.south) -- (6.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b6);
%\path (7.north) -- (7.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a7);
%\path (7.south) -- (7.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b7);
\draw[->] (0) to node {} (1);
\draw[->] (a1) to node {\footnotesize$\beta SZ$} (b1);
\path (1.east) -- (1.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a2);
\path (2.west) -- (2.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b2);
\draw[->] (a2) to[swap] node {\footnotesize$\delta S$} (b2);
\draw[->] (3) to node{} (5);
\draw[->] (2) to node{} (4);
\draw[->] (2) to node{\footnotesize $\alpha\lambda E$} (3);
%\draw[->] (1) to[in=135,out=45]  node{\footnotesize$\zeta S$} (6);
\draw[->] (1) -- +(0,1cm) -| (6);
\node[above=1cm] at ($(1)!0.5!(6)$){\footnotesize$\zeta S$};
\draw[->] ([xshift=-0.3cm]6.south) -- +(0,-1cm) node[below]{\footnotesize$\delta V$};
\draw[->] ([xshift=0.3cm]6.south)  -- +(0,-1cm) node[below]{\footnotesize$\beta VZ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Something likes this.  The solution changes/modifies the last 3 lines. Also some labels are changes to meet the drawing on article. As to the coloring of each block, try the following

```
fill=cyan!30!white, fill=red!30!white, fill=green!30!white
```

[image]Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,positioning,shapes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{node distance=2.3cm, auto}
\node (0) {\footnotesize$\pi (S+V)$};
\node (1) [right of=0, xshift = -0.5cm, shape=rectangle,draw=black, fill=cyan] {$S$}; 
\node (2) [right of=1, shape=rectangle,draw=black, fill=white] {$E$};
\node (3) [right of=2, shape = rectangle, draw = black, fill = red] {$Z$};
\node (4) [below of=2, yshift=1cm] {\footnotesize$(1-\alpha)\chi E$};
\node (5) [below of=3, yshift=1cm] {\footnotesize$\gamma (S+ V)Z$};
\node (6) [right of = 3, draw = black, fill = green] {$V$};
\node (7) [below of=6, shape = rectangle, yshift=1cm, text = white] {$V$};
\path (1.east) -- (1.north east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a1);
\path (2.west) -- (2.north west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b1);  
\path (6.south) -- (6.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a6);
\path (6.south) -- (6.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b6);
\path (7.north) -- (7.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a7);
\path (7.south) -- (7.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b7);
\draw[->] (0) to node {} (1);
\draw[->] (a1) to node {\footnotesize$\beta SZ$} (b1);
\path (1.east) -- (1.south east) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a2);
\path (2.west) -- (2.south west) coordinate[pos=0.5] (b2);
\draw[->] (a2) to[swap] node {\footnotesize$\delta S$} (b2);
\draw[->] (3) to node{} (5);
\draw[->] (2) to node{} (4);
\draw[->] (2) to node{\footnotesize $\alpha\lambda E$} (3);
%\draw[->] (1) to[in=135,out=45]  node{\footnotesize$\zeta S$} (6);
\draw[->] (1) -- +(0,1cm)   -| (6);
\node[above=1cm] at ($(1)!0.5!(6)$){\footnotesize$\zeta S$};
\draw[->] (a6) -- (a7) node[below]{\footnotesize$\delta V$};
\draw[->] (b6) --  (b7)node[below]{\footnotesize$\beta VZ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.28,-1.82)(7,1.84) % found manually
 {\psset{fillstyle = solid} \Large
  \psframe[fillcolor = blue!30](0,0)(1,1)
  \rput(0.5,0.5){$S$}
  \psframe(2,0)(3,1)
  \rput(2.5,0.5){$E$}
  \psframe[fillcolor = red!30](4,0)(5,1)
  \rput(4.5,0.5){$Z$}
  \psframe[fillcolor = green!30](6,0)(7,1)
  \rput(6.5,0.5){$V$}}
 {\psset{arrows = ->, labelsep = 2.5pt} \footnotesize
  \psline(-1,0.5)(0,0.5)
  \psline(!1 2 3 div)(!2 2 3 div)
  \psline(!1 1 3 div)(!2 1 3 div)
  \psline(3,0.5)(4,0.5)
  \psline(2.5,0)(2.5,-1)
  \psline(4.5,0)(4.5,-1)
  \psline(0.5,1)(0.5,1.5)(6.5,1.5)(6.5,1)
  \psline(!19 3 div 0)(!19 3 div -1)
  \psline(!20 3 div 0)(!20 3 div -1.5)
  \uput[180](-1,0.5){$\pi(S + V)$}
  \uput[90](!1.5 2 3 div){$\beta SZ$}
  \uput[270](!1.5 1 3 div){$\delta S$}
  \uput[90](3.5,0.5){$\alpha\lambda E$}
  \uput[270](2.5,-1){$(1 - \alpha)\chi E$}
  \uput[270](4.5,-1){$\gamma(S + V)Z$}
  \uput[90](3.5,1.5){$\zeta S$}
  \uput[270](!19 3 div -1){$\delta V$}
  \uput[270](!20 3 div -1.5){$\beta V{\mkern -2mu}Z$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]