# Extending anchors in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

The following are the standard anchors available in TikZ (to the best of my knowledge):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{dot/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    draw   = black,
    fill = black,
    minimum size = 0.2cm
}}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
        shape  = rectangle,
        draw   = black,
        minimum height = 10cm,
        minimum width  = 10cm
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (a) at (0,0) [squarenode] {};
  \node[label=a.center] at (a.center) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north] at (a.north) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south] at (a.south) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.east] at (a.east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.west] at (a.west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north east] at (a.north east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north west] at (a.north west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south east] at (a.south east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south west] at (a.south west) [dot] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, how do I locate the following points:

1. Point between a.south and a.south west (midpoint and normal point - any point on the line)
2. Point between a.south west and a.center (midpoint and normal point - any point on the line)

Comment: If you want to add *new* anchors to an existing shape, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14769/86

Comment: There are also `.base`, `.base east`, `.base west` and all the `.<angle>` for the standard rectangle shape.

Answer (score 12):

You can gan get points on a line between two nodes with `coordinate[pos=x]`, where `x` is a fraction. so

```
\path (a.south west) -- (a.south) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a-mid-sw);
```

will give you the point in the middle between `(a.south west)` and `(a.south)`. If you choose `x` smaller/larger, it will be closer to  `(a.south west)`/`(a-mid-sw)`, and for `x=0` or `x=1` it will coincide with `(a.south west)` or `(a.south)` respectively. Note that `x` can be negative or larger than `1`, in which case the coordinate will be located outside the line connecting the points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{dot/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    draw   = black,
    fill = black,
    minimum size = 0.2cm
}}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
        shape  = rectangle,
        draw   = black,
        minimum height = 10cm,
        minimum width  = 10cm
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (a) at (0,0) [squarenode] {};
  \node[label=a.center] at (a.center) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north] at (a.north) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south] at (a.south) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.east] at (a.east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.west] at (a.west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north east] at (a.north east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north west] at (a.north west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south east] at (a.south east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south west] at (a.south west) [dot] {};
  \path (a.south west) -- (a.south) coordinate[pos=0.5] (a-mid-sw)
(a.south west) -- (a.center) coordinate[pos=0.3] (a-diag);
  \node[label=a-mid-sw] at (a-mid-sw) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a-diag] at (a-diag) [dot] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `calc` library also allows you to mix coordinates. And you can get points on the boundary using `a.angle`, where the angle has to be specified in degrees. `a.90`, for instance, is the same as `a.north`, `a.0` the same as `a.east` but in general `a.45` and `a.north east` do not have to coincide. (Here they do because the shape is a square.) If you want to have additional anchors, you may define a new shape.

Answer (score 7):

Another way using `calc` library (node labels are inspired by [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482058/156344))

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\tikzset{dot/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    draw   = black,
    fill = black,
    minimum size = 0.2cm
}}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
        shape  = rectangle,
        draw   = black,
        minimum height = 10cm,
        minimum width  = 10cm
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (a) at (0,0) [squarenode] {};
  \node[label=a.center] at (a.center) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north] at (a.north) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south] at (a.south) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.east] at (a.east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.west] at (a.west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north east] at (a.north east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north west] at (a.north west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south east] at (a.south east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south west] at (a.south west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a-mid-sw] at ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south)$) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a-diag] at ($(a.south west)!.3!(a.center)$) [dot] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you are using this a lot, I suggest using a macro

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\tikzset{dot/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    draw   = black,
    fill = black,
    minimum size = 0.2cm
}}

\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
        shape  = rectangle,
        draw   = black,
        minimum height = 10cm,
        minimum width  = 10cm
}}
\def\findmid#1#2#3{($(#2)!#1!(#3)$)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
  \node (a) at (0,0) [squarenode] {};
  \node[label=a.center] at (a.center) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north] at (a.north) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south] at (a.south) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.east] at (a.east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.west] at (a.west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north east] at (a.north east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.north west] at (a.north west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south east] at (a.south east) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a.south west] at (a.south west) [dot] {};
  \node[label=a-mid-sw] at \findmid{0.5}{a.south west}{a.south} [dot] {};
  \node[label=a-diag] at \findmid{0.3}{a.south west}{a.center} [dot] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(the same output as above)