# adjustwidth not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, adjustwidth

When I used adjustwidth on a long circuit, the entire figure appears. But when I added a figure before that circuit, it just performs as if adjustwidth wasn't there (i.e. part of it gets clipped on the right side of the page). Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts,bm}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta, positioning}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfaddtoshape#1#2{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14772/38080
    \begingroup
    \def\pgf@sm@shape@name{#1}%
    \let\anchor\pgf@sh@anchor
    #2%
    \endgroup
}
% we need to add an anchor to muxdemux
\pgfaddtoshape{muxdemux}{
    \anchor{top left ext}{%
        \topleft\advance\pgf@x by -\extshift
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{block/.style={draw, rectangle, 
            minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
        sum/.style={draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
        input/.style={coordinate},
        output/.style={coordinate},
        pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}}}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            % The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=Latex, scale = 0.85, transform shape]
            % We start by placing the blocks
            \node [input, name=input, label={left:$y\left(t\right)$}] {};
            \node [sum, right of=input, node distance = 2cm, name = sum1] {};
            \node [block, right of= sum1, node distance = 2.5cm] (int1) {$\dfrac{1}{s}$};
            \node [block, right of= int1, node distance = 3 cm] (int2) {$\dfrac{1}{s}$};
            \node [block, below of= int1, node distance = 1.75 cm] (bgain) {$b$};
            \node [block, right of= int2, node distance = 3 cm] (again) {$a$};
            \node [sum, right of= again, node distance = 2 cm, name = sum2] {};
            \node [block, right of= sum2, node distance = 2 cm] (Kgain) {$K$};
            \node [output, right of= Kgain, node distance = 2 cm, label={right:$u\left(t\right)$}] (output) {};
            % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy.
            \draw [draw,->] (input) --node[pos=0.92] {$+$} (sum1);
            \draw [->] (bgain) -| node[pos=0.92] {$-$} (sum1);
            \draw [->] (sum1) -- node [name = zddot, pos = 0.5]{$\ddot{z}$}(int1);
            \draw [->] (int1) -- node [name = zdot, pos = 0.5]{$\dot{z}$}(int2);
            \draw [->] (int2) -- node [name = z, pos = 0.5]{$z$}(again);
            \draw [->] (again) -- node[pos=0.92] {$+$} (sum2);
            \draw [->] (sum2) -- (Kgain);
            \draw [->] (Kgain) -- (output);
            \draw [->] (zdot) -- (zdot |- bgain) -- (bgain);
            \draw [->] (zdot |- bgain) -| node[pos=0.92] {$+$} (sum2);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Extended control block diagram for Problem 1b.}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            % The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
            \begin{circuitikz}[
                ]
                \tikzset{small text/.style={
                        font=\tiny,
                        right,
                        inner xsep=1pt,
                    },
                }
                \draw (9, 5) node[muxdemux, no input leads, muxdemux def={Lh=3, NL=2, w=3, Rh=0, NR=1}](sum1){$\sum\quad$};
                \draw (sum1.blpin 1) node[small text]{$1$} to[short] ++(-1, 0) node[left]{$y\left(t\right)$};
                \draw (sum1.blpin 2) node[small text]{$-b$};
                \draw (sum1.brpin 1) -- ++ (0.5, 0) node [label={[shift={(0,-0.2)}]above:$\ddot{z}$}]{} -- ++ (0.6, 0) node[muxdemux, no input leads, muxdemux def={Lh=2, NL=3, w=2, Rh=0, NR=1}, anchor=lpin 2] (int1){$\int\quad$};
                \draw[line width=0.8pt] (int1.north west -| int1.lpin 2) rectangle (int1.south west -| int1.blpin 2);
                \node [small text] at (int1.lpin 2) {$1$};
                \draw (int1.brpin 1) -- ++ (0.5, 0) node [label={[shift={(0,-0.2)}]above:$\dot{z}$}]{} coordinate (dotz) -- ++ (0.6, 0) node[muxdemux, no input leads, muxdemux def={Lh=2, NL=3, w=2, Rh=0, NR=1}, anchor=lpin 2] (int2){$\int\quad$};
                \draw[line width=0.8pt] (int2.north west -| int2.lpin 2) rectangle (int2.south west -| int2.blpin 2);
                \node [small text] at (int2.lpin 2) {$1$};
                \draw (dotz) -- ++ (0, -1.5) coordinate (belowDotZ) -- ++ (-5, 0) |- (sum1.blpin 2);
                \draw (int2.brpin 1) -- ++ (0.5, 0) node [label={[shift={(0,-0.2)}]above:$z$}]{} -- ++ (0.6, 0) node[muxdemux, no input leads, muxdemux def={Lh=3, NL=2, w=3, Rh=0, NR=1}, anchor = blpin 1](sum2){$\sum\quad$};
                \draw (sum2.blpin 1) node[small text]{$a$};
                \draw (sum2.blpin 2) node[small text]{$1$} -- ++ (-0.5, 0) |- (belowDotZ);
                \draw (sum2.brpin 1) -- ++ (1.1, 0) node[muxdemux, no input leads, muxdemux def={Lh=2, NL=1, w=2, Rh=0, NR=1}, anchor=blpin 1] (gain){$K\quad$};
                \draw (gain.brpin 1) -- ++(0.5, 0) node[right]{$u\left(t\right)$};
            \end{circuitikz}
            \caption{Analog computer diagram for Problem 1b.}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-5em} 
                \begin{circuitikz}[scale = 0.55, transform shape]
                    \draw (9, 5) node [op amp] (FBOA) {};
                    \draw (FBOA.-) to[short, -*] ++ (-1.5, 0) coordinate (FBOAnegBreak) to[R, l_=$R_\textrm{FB1}$, -o] ++ (-3, 0)node[label={left:$y\left(t\right)$}]{};
                    \draw (FBOAnegBreak) to[R, l_=$R_\textrm{FB2}$] ++ (0, -5) coordinate (FB2);
                    \draw (FBOAnegBreak) -- ++ (0, 1.5) to [R, l^=$R_\textrm{FB,out}$] ++ (3.5, 0) -| (FBOA.out);
                    \draw (FBOA.+) node[ground]{};
                    \draw (FBOA.out) node[label={below:$-\ddot{z}\left(t\right)$}]{} to [R, l^=$R_\textrm{int1,in}$] ++ (3, 0) node [op amp, anchor = -] (int1) {};
                    \draw (int1.+) node[ground]{};
                    \draw (FBOA |- FB2) node [op amp, xscale = -1] (bOA){};
                    \draw (bOA.+) node[ground]{};
                    \draw (bOA.out) -- (FB2);
                    \draw (int1.-) -- ++ (0, 1.5) to [C, l^=$C_\textrm{int1,out}$] ++ (2.5, 0) coordinate (nearInt1Out) |- (int1.out);
                    \draw (bOA.-) to [R, l^= $R_{b,\textrm{in}}$] ++ (3, 0) coordinate (bOANegIn);
                    \draw (nearInt1Out |- int1.out) node[label={below right:$\dot{z}\left(t\right)$}]{} |- (bOANegIn);
                    \draw (bOA.-) -- ++ (0, 1.5) to [R, l_=$R_{b,\textrm{out}}$] ++ (-2.5, 0) coordinate (nearbOAOut) -- (bOA.out-|nearbOAOut) node[label={below:$-b\dot{z}\left(t\right)$}]{};
                    \draw (nearInt1Out) |- (int1.out) to [R, l^=$R_\textrm{int2,in}$] ++ (3, 0) node [op amp, anchor = -] (int2) {};
                    \draw (int2.+) node[ground]{};
                    \draw (int2.-) -- ++ (0, 1.5) to [C, l^=$C_\textrm{int2,out}$] ++ (2.5, 0) coordinate (nearInt2Out) |- (int2.out);
                    \draw (nearInt2Out) |- (int2.out) node[label={below:$-z\left(t\right)$}]{} to [R, l^=$R_{a,\textrm{in}}$] ++ (3, 0) node [op amp, anchor = -] (aOA) {};
                    \draw (aOA.+) node[ground]{};
                    \draw (aOA.-) -- ++ (0, 1.5) to [R, l^=$R_{a,\textrm{out}}$] ++ (2.5, 0) coordinate (nearaOAOut) |- (aOA.out);
                    \draw (nearaOAOut |- aOA.out) node[label={below:$az\left(t\right)$}]{} to [R, l^= $R_\textrm{sum,1}$,-*] ++ (3, 0) coordinate (nearSumNeg) to[short] ++ (1, 0) node [op amp, anchor = -] (summer) {};
                    \draw (summer.+) node[ground]{};
                    \draw (nearSumNeg) -- (nearSumNeg |- bOANegIn) to [R, l_= $R_\textrm{sum,2}$] ++ (-3, 0) -- (bOANegIn);
                    \draw (nearSumNeg) -- ++ (0, 1.5) to [R, l^=$R_\textrm{sum,out}$] ++ (3, 0) -| (summer.out);
                    \draw (summer.out) node[label={below:$x\left(t\right)$}]{} to [R, l^= $R_{K,\textrm{in}}$] ++ (3, 0) node [op amp, anchor = -] (KOA) {};
                    \draw (KOA.+) node[ground]{};
                    \draw (KOA.-) -- ++ (0, 1.5) to [R, l^=$R_{K,\textrm{out}}$] ++ (2.5, 0) coordinate (nearKOAOut) |- (KOA.out);
                    \draw (nearKOAOut |- KOA.out) to [short, -o] ++ (0.5, 0) node[label={right:$u\left(t\right)$}]{};
                \end{circuitikz}
            \end{adjustwidth*}
            \caption{Circuit for Problem 1b.}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Picture:
[image]

Can someone explain what is going on with `adjustwidth`?

Comment: Are you ignoring errors? I'd expect adjustwidth to be given two arguments, both lengths, you're leaving one empty. Plus what exactly are you expecting adjustwidth to do here?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, and in fact, I am trying to shift the Figure 6 to the left so that the entire figure doesn't go off the page.

Comment: You need the left arg for that, a negative arg will move the gig into the left margin. You're currently just making space for it into the tight margin

Comment: Can you show me how I should code it then so that the long circuit will shift left and be entirely seen as desired?

Comment: See what happens if you give it a negative length in the first argument (the one currently empty)

Comment: Does the provided answer answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... let me say that this is not a *minimal* example, but well... I will put here only the changes.

The main problem is the use of `adjustwidth`, as noticed by @daelif --- I simply do not know from where it comes (not in found in `adjustbox` manual I have). If you change  your `adjustwidth` environment with:

```latex
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
...
\end{adjustbox}
```

everything works, although there are still some points to take into account:

1. If you rescale the circuit, using `[scale=0.55, transform shape]` is simply try to test the limits of PGF math precision... better remove it.
2. You should look at the warnings. Add one of the voltage options to `circuitikz` (you'll regret that in the future otherwise) like

   ```
   \usepackage[american,siunitx,RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
   ```
3. On the same line, add

   ```
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
   ```

   (or whichever version you have) to have future-proof diagrams.

Finally, the resulting circuit:

[image: final circuit]

is in my opinion too small to be easily read --- consider putting it on two lines, or at least make the fonts bigger (and you need a connection dot on the output on the first integrator!).